# Isolate the speech of two people in an audio record with two people only

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, python, audio-processing

I would like to find a way to isolate the speech of each of the people in an audio record so I can create a file of that form :

```
[
   {
       "voice_fingerprint": "701066EDD3A0A40A2F53F61EAFD0E6AB",
       "sentences": {
           {
               "sentence": "do you like red apples",
               "position": 1.39 // Seconds. Time position in the audio record
           },
           {
               "sentence": "and how do you feel about time shifts",
               "position": 7.21
           }
       }
   },
   {
       "voice_fingerprint": "8FFEA051AF3E3FB9A80A51A98FE05896",
       "sentences": {
           {
               "sentence": "yes I do like them",
               "position": 4.54
           },
           {
               "sentence": "i feel well about traveling",
               "position": 10.18
           }
       }
   }
]
```

This may be an interview record.

The problem **IS NOT** the Speech to Text, but to **isolate the two people's sentences**. Preferably in Python.

Have you ever worked on this ? Do you have any hints ?

Comment: For anyone working on this kind of topic : the technology is called "diarisation". But this is quite new and even Google or IBM APIs don't give good results.

Answer (score 1):

The task of isolating 2 or more speakers is called `speaker diarization`,
[here](https://github.com/wq2012/awesome-diarization#software) a list of softwares and useful resources.

Once you have the 2 or more audio files containing the individual voices, you could run some speech-to-text network that also outputs time information.